# Toggle with multiple actions

Tags: jquery

I have a div with a lot of events. I tried two things:

1- Do the second part of the toggle with a conditional. It works but the response is not perfect, there is a delay of a second. I simplified the case here: http://jsfiddle.net/T26vF/2/

2-Then I tried with a simple toggle. When I click to an object it works ok. But here the problem is that when I'm in the first part of the toggle and I click to the background or to the other object and come back to the first object I have to click twice, (the first click still executes the second part of the toggle). I simplified the case here: http://jsfiddle.net/T26vF/4/

```
$(function(){

    // THIS
    $(".arrodonit").toggle(
        function(){ $(this).children("img").animate({"width":"411px","marginLeft": "-85px","marginTop": "-80px"}, 900); 
                    $(this).siblings(".fons").fadeOut("slow");
                  },

        function(){ $(this).children("img").animate({"width":"233px","marginLeft": "0px","marginTop": "0px"}, 900); 
                    $(this).siblings(".fons").fadeIn("slow");
        }
    );

    // NOT THIS
    $(".arrodonit").click(function(e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        $('.arrodonit').not(this).siblings(".fons").fadeIn("slow");
        $('.arrodonit').not(this).children("img").stop().animate({ "width":"233px","marginLeft": "0px","marginTop": "0px",}, 900);
        $(".mesInfo").fadeIn()
        $(".info").fadeOut()
    });

    // DOCUMENT
    $(document).click(function() {
       $('.fons').fadeIn();
       $('.arrodonit img').animate({ "width":"233px","marginLeft": "0px","marginTop": "0px"}, 900); 
    });

})
```

I ask:
- What is wrong with my code?
- Why there is a delay if I make a conditional in the first case?
- Why I have to click twice in the second example?
- Is there a better way to do the same actions?

Answer (score 0):

This is just a trick,
try using `stop().animate()` when you have a sequence of animation events, this will cut down your delay

Hope this helps

Comment: What you say makes sense but I try to put .stop().animate for instance in the document and it don't work. If I click the first part of the toggle, then click the document and then click once again to the object and I have to click twice. I suppose that when I click the document it needs to quit the toggle and with the stop(); it doesn't happen. You can see it here: http://jsfiddle.net/T26vF/5/ Perhaps there is something i do wrong.

Comment: why dont you have stop in other animates where it makes sense as well

Comment: I put stop(). in all and nothing changes. http://jsfiddle.net/T26vF/9/  You can do it yourself, you can change it directly.